# Prove that $I_{m, n} = I_{m+1,n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $I_{m,n} = \dfrac{1}{m!n!}\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^ndx$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z},m,n \geq 0$. Prove that $I_{m,n}=I_{m+1,n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$.

I thought of proving this by induction, with $P(n)$ being the statement that $I_{m,n} = I_{m+1,n-1}.$ I can prove the base case, but I'm having difficulty proving the inductive step. I tried using the hypothesis (i.e., $\dfrac{1}{m!k!}\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^m (1-x)^kdx=\dfrac{1}{(m+1)!(k-1)!}\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{m+1}(1-x)^{k-1}dx$). But I'm not sure how to prove $I_{m,k+1} = I_{m+1,k}$ using integration by parts.

Comment: hint: when doing the integration by parts, let $u = (1-x)^n$ and $dv = x^mdx$.

Comment: yeah. in fact you don't even need induction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing $m$ by $m+1$ in $x^m$ is antidifferentiating (modulo multiplication by a constant).

Replacing $n$ by $n-1$ in $(1-x)^n$ is differentiating (modulo multiplication by a constant).

Differentiating one factor and antidifferentiating the other is exactly what happens in integration by parts.

So integrate by parts:
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^n\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 (1-x)^n \Big( x^m \, dx\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int u \,dv = uv - \int v\,du \\[10pt]
= {} & \left[ (1-x)^n \frac{x^{m+1}} {m+1} \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{m+1}} {m+1} \cdot n(1-x)^{n-1}(-1) \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac n {m+1} \int_0^1 x^{m+1} (1-x)^{n-1} \, dx.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate $I_{m,n}$ by parts. Taking $u=(1-x)^n$ and $dv=x^mdx$ the integration by parts formula

$$\int_0^1u\cdot dv =\left[u\cdot v\right]_0^1-\int_0^1v\cdot du$$

gives

$$I_{m,n}={1\over m!n!}\left[(1-x)^n{x^m\over m+1}\right]_0^1+{1\over (m+1)!(n-1)!}\int_0^1x^{m+1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx$$

Comment: Thanks just edited

Comment: I'd write $\displaystyle \left[(1-x)^n{x^m\over m+1} \right]_0^1$ rather than $\displaystyle [(1-x)^n{x^m\over m+1}]_0^1$ and $\displaystyle \int u\,dv$ (etc.) instead of $\displaystyle \int u dv. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for induction.

Integration by parts will do. 
$$\int _0^1 x^m(1-x)^ndx  =$$

$$(1-x)^n \frac {x^{m+1}}{m+1}|_0^1 -\int _0^1\frac {x^{m+1}}{m+1}n(1-x)^{n-1}(-1)dx=$$

$$\frac{n}{m+1}\int _0^1 x^{m+1}(1-x)^{n-1}dx$$

Upon substitution you get the desired result.